# Conditionally adding extra else if statements

Tags: java, android, if-statement, methods, code-duplication

The following is called from every level of my app (a game)

**Pseudo code example**

```
public void checkCollisions(){

    if (someCondition)
        do something

    else if (someCondition2)
        do something2

    else if (someCondition3)
        do something3

}
```

It's called like so:

```
mainGame.checkCollisions();
```

However, in selected levels, I need to throw in an additional condition, so instead of duplicating the whole method like..........

```
 public void checkCollisions2(){

    if (someCondition)
        do something

    else if (someCondition2)
        do something2

    else if (someCondition3)
        do something3

    else if (someCondition4)
        do something4

}
```

and then calling it like..........

```
mainGame.checkCollisions2();
```

I need to find a way to do this more efficiently (I'm sure there is one)  The only way I can think of is taking in a boolean and then either carrying out the 4th condition (or not) depending on what the value of the boolean is, but that just doesn't seem a great way of doing it either (say, for example if I want to add even more conditions in the future).

This has to be an 'else if' statement so I can't just it into a separate method that I can call in addition to the original method.

Options would be appreciated

Comment: Taking another `boolean` seems like a perfectly reasonable approach, or if you need to add different checks for different levels, maybe make your levels into an enum and override an extra check method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have `checkCollisions` return a `boolean` that indicates whether it "did something".

```
public boolean checkCollisions(){
    boolean didSomething = false;
    if (someCondition) {
       doSomething();
       didSomething = true;
    }
    else if (condition2) {
       doSomething2();
       didSomething = true;
    } 
    else if (condition3){
       doSomething3();
       didSomething = true;
    }
    return didSomething;
}
```

Then, `checkCollisions2` can call `checkCollisions` and check if it did something.  Then your `else if` can work normally:

```
public void checkCollisions2(){
    if (checkCollisions()) {
       // Yes, something was done!
    }
    else if (condition4) {
       doSomething4();
    }
}
```

or shorter:

```
public void checkCollisions2(){
    if (!checkCollisions() && condition4) {
       doSomething4();
    }
}
```